# uibutton won't disable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

I created a UIButton programmatically and added it to the subview of a UIScrollView. Later in a different portion of the code, I need to disable the button. When I attempt to refer back to the button, however, it will not disable.

Heres some code:

*Header:*

```
UIButton *button1;
```

*Main:*

```
 button1 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
 [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonStuff) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [scrollView addSubview:button1];
```

*When I try to disable button1:*

```
        NSLog(@"Hidden state: %i", button1.hidden);  //------> returns "0" 
        button1.enabled = NO;
        button1.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"Hidden state: %i", button1.hidden);  //------> returns "1", yet is not hidden on screen
```

The interesting thing to note is that in the last peice of code, before I hide the button, my NSLog returns a 0 (not hidden). Then, when I attempt to hide it, NSLog returns a 1, denoting that the button has been hidden - yet it continues to be completely visible on screen and not disabled either. I am very confused. Can someone help me out on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Here was the problem: (silly actually)

If you are drawing UI elements inside the `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method - be careful because this method gets executed often.

My button was being disabled and hidden in a later part of my code, but only milliseconds later, the method above was being called again without my knowledge. This drew the UIButton again and made it look like my disable commands were not working.

Answer (score 0):

Is the button-hiding code getting called an a background thread?  UIKit is not threadsafe; modifying properties of UIKit objects on threads other than the main thread can result in not seeing updates to visual properties, or there may be long delays before you see the changes.

You can make sure that a method is run on the main thread via `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.

Comment: It should be executing on the main thread. Here is the what it is executing inside of: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you updating the UI in that method?

Comment: When the user reloads the table view, I need to draw some new UI stuff. I figure the easiest way to invoke the new drawing for right now is to do it inside that method I mentioned above because it gets run every time the table view refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

You are abusing the method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. Instead, you should crate your own method and call `[self.tableView reloadData];` from there.